# Getting Invalid data on decode using appache common-codec library

Tags: java, ssl, encode, pkcs#12

I have scenario where I am getting my pkcs12 cert content as encoded string(appache common-codec library). Now I have to decode that string and have to store it file. But while decoding it as a string I am getting an invalid cert content.

When I am trying to write bytes in a file it works fine. Please find the snippets I have tried below.

For encode:

```
Base64.encodeBase64String(certcontentInBytes[])
```

For decode:

```
new String(Base64.decodeBase64(certstringContent));
```

Comment: Hey all after debugging few times I came to know that base64 encode and decode on appache is using iso_8859_1 format,but On my x509Certificate conversion I have used UTF-8 which causes the problem.When changed evryting as iso_8859_1,it works fine

Answer (score 0):

`new String(bytes)` actually does `new String(bytes, defaultCharset)` to convert the bytes using the charset of the bytes to a Unicode string. Non-portable and probable wrong charset.

For bytes as binary data that will not work. String should not be used for binary data. I bet the *bytes* were written to the file.

Comment: yeah, while decoding and writing into a file with decoded bytes it works well.But when I am trying to convert it to a string its giving invalid string.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to use `new String(byte[], Charset charset)` with the correct charset (probably UTF-8), because otherwise it will use the platform charset, which differs between Windows and Linux/Unix.
I wonder why you can't simply use the byte array as parameter?

Comment: thanks for the reply.I even tried with those possibilities as well.

Comment: Without knowing your code: Saving the bytes to a file and then using that file works, but converting the bytes to a string and that string doesn't work - it sounds almost as if the code you use handles files and strings differently.
I strongly suggest you wrap your bytes in an `ByteArrayInputStream` and use that as a replacement for a `FileInputStream`, which stands (most probably) behind the file usage.